# Conservation of enegry in case of Exploding Projectile

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, projectile

Consider the following problem :

> A projectile of mass **M** explodes, while in flight, into three fragments. One fragment of mass $m_1 =\frac12 M$ travels in the original direction of the projectile. Another fragment of mass $m_2 =\frac16 M$ travels in the opposite direction and the third fragment of mass $m_3 =\frac13 M$ comes to rest.
>
> The energy $E$, released in the explosion, is 5 times the kinetic energy of the projectile at explosion. What are the velocities of the fragments?

Let us try to apply conservation of energy at the point the projectile explodes.

Since all the fragmented particles will be at very same height at the instant of the explosion then there will be no difference in their potential energies. Only the kinetic energy of the projectile will affect how fast the particles move apart.  So how could the loss be 5 times?  I mean I can't understand conservation of energy in this case.

Comment: what's not to understand? A process within the original object adds kinetic energy to the system. Assuming no heat or light were released in the explosion (pretty lame explosion), you just use conservation of energy to figure out new, faster velocities for all the fragments that conserves the initial momentum AND the total energy the system now has

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that KE of the projectile AFTER the explosion is 5X the KE before the explosion?  If that is the case you cannot use conservation of energy, since Ef is not = to Ei.

Comment: However, since Ef = 5*Ei you can say: MVi^2 = 5[m1*V1^2+m2*V2^2]  You can cancel your m1 and m2 with the above mass relations.  That leaves just the velocities and three unknowns, unless you are given Vi.  You would need a second equation to solve for V1 and V2.  But this is as far as i've gotten with the given problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must look at all forms of energy.

Just before the explosion, the projectile has gravitational potential energy GPE, kinetic energy KE, and also chemical potential energy CPE stored in the dynamite.

Just after the explosion the 3 fragments all have the same GPE as before.  The CPE has disappeared in the explosion.  As Jim says, we must assume that it is converted completely into KE, and none (or a negligible amount) into light, heat and sound.  The total KE has *increased by* 5x what it was before the explosion, so the final KE is 6x the initial value.  Another way of putting this is that the CPE was 5x the initial KE, which is just what is written in the question.

Momentum must also be conserved.

Comment: Nice explanation.So essentially  assuming CPE = E we can apply conservation of momentum and conservation of energy to get two equations. but I can see at least 3 variable here v0, v1, v2. here v0 is velocity of projectile just before explosion and v1 and v2 is velocities of first and second fragments just after explosion. Can u please suggest any other equation in order to represent all velocities in term of E. Many Thanks

Comment: You will have to express the final velocities in terms of v0, which is not given in the question.  So there are really only two unknowns : v1/v0 and v2/v0.